# Annual Probability Over Time When Not Exactly Independent

Tags: probability, time-series

I haven't found an answer to this specific question. Say that I have a 1% chance of my appendix bursting in any given year. To calculate the probability over twenty years, if these were considered individual events, I would compute 1 - ( 0.99) ^ 20.

However, if my appendix bursts in year two, the probability of it bursting in years three through twenty is zero because there's no more appendix. Should I think of this scenario as independent and just calculate as above (again, looking for the probability of appendix burst in any of those twenty years)? Or should I take into account that the event in question can only happen once and therefore calculate differently?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $1-(.99)^{20}$ is correct :)

Comment: Do you mean instead "*Say that I have a 1% chance of my appendix bursting in any given year* **given that I still have my appendix in that year.**"  This is a rather important nuanced distinction.  The answer will again be $1-0.99^{20}$ that your appendix did burst in that time.  The question of *how many times* will always be one or zero, unlike in binomial distributions... and instead of *how many times* the common question is *how soon*.  See the Geometric Distribution.

Comment: You could think about playing the lottery instead. As you already seem to know, the probability of winning at least once over $20$ attempts is $1-(0.99)^{20}$. But in analogy with the appendix example, let's say you decide to stop opening your remaing lottery tickets as soon as you win. Well, all the unopened lottery don't know that you stopped opening them, so the probability is unchanged. Does that make any sense at all?  It's a matter of whether you observe the outcome or not on the last ones, but they still have a "hidden" outcome either way.

Comment: You guys rock! Thank you.